# Approximation of Simple functions by Step functions

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-measure

In this question, all measures are Lebesgue.

Let $ E $ be a measurable set. Is it true that for every $ \epsilon > 0 $, there is a step function $ \gamma : \mathbb{R} \longmapsto \mathbb{R} $ such that the set $ \left \{x   \in   \mathbb{R}   |  \gamma(x) \neq   \chi_{E}  (x)   \right \} $ has measure less than $    \epsilon $? Here $ \chi_{E} :   \mathbb{R}  \longmapsto  \mathbb{R}  $ is the indicator function for $ E $, and so, it assumes values $ 1 $ when $ x \in E $ and $ 0 $ otherwise.

Note 1: I can do the proof when $ E $ has finite measure. The case $ m(E) = \infty $ is driving me nuts.

Note 2: I have another problem that may not be relevant here. Does a step function allow degenerate intervals? So, can a step function (which assumes finitely many values) be like $ f(x) = 2 $ for $ x < 2  \wedge x > 2$, and $ f(x) = 1 $ at $ x = 1 $?

Answer (score 0):

Noting feels better than answering your own question, especially one as trivial as this.

So, let $ E =   \bigcup _{  n \in \mathbb{Z} }   [2n, 2n+1)    $. If $ \gamma $ is any step function, then, it must be constant on an interval of the form $ (a, \infty) $ or $ [a, \infty)  $. In that case, $ \gamma  $ is not equal to $    \chi_{E} $ on either $ E \cap  (a+1,    \infty) $ or $  (  \mathbb{R} - E ) \cap  ( a+ 1, \infty )  $, both of which have infinite measure.

Also, wikipedia mentions that sum and product of two step functions is a step function. Consider the functions $ s_{1} $ which assume value $ 1 $ for $ x < 0 $ and $ 2 $ for $ x \geq 0 $ and $ s_{2} $ which assumes value $ 3 $ for $ x \leq 0 $ and $ 1 $ on $ x > 0 $. The sum of these two functions is a step function which has a degenerate interval.